# angular-translate link not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I can't make a link to another language with angular-translate.

```
var translations = {
  "en": {
    "HELLO": "hello",
    "ORANGE": "orange"
  },
  "fr": {
    "HELLO": "salut",
    "ORANGE": "@:en.ORANGE"
  },
};
```

See the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XwASOZsF0vLOoEqGEQ1i?p=preview).

It displays "en.ORANGE" instead of "orange".

For reference, see the [documentation](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/02_getting-started), section "Shortcuts and Links".

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? That is, what isn't working? Is there a reason to even have the @en part?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to refer to another language. Where did you find the '@:' notation?

Comment: @fikkatra: [here](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/02_getting-started) in section "Shortcuts and Links".

Comment: @kirkpatt: just trying to link a label from a namespace to another one, as described [here](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/02_getting-started) in section "Shortcuts and Links".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NAMESPACE` in the documentation refers to the one within the same language.

In your plunker, you have this:

```
var translations = {
  "en": {
    "HELLO": "hello",
    "ORANGE": "orange"
  },
  "fr": {
    "HELLO": "salut",
    "ORANGE": "@:en.ORANGE"
  },
};
$translateProvider
  .translations('en', translations['en'])
  .translations('fr', translations['fr'])
```

When you set `.translations('fr', translations['fr'])`, you have this as the namespace for your French language:

```
{
  "HELLO": "salut",
  "ORANGE": "@:en.ORANGE"
}
```

And whenever `angular-translate` searches for `en.ORANGE`, it searches within the above object.

The feature of using the translation from other language is not implemented (yet). Taking a look at the source code for the `angular-translate`, there's this bit of code:

```
if (translation.substr(0, 2) === '@:') {
          getFallbackTranslation(langKey, translation.substr(2), interpolateParams, Interpolator)
            .then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
        } else {...}
```

Whenever you have the `@:` chars, it does not change the `langKey`, meaning it will search for the translation in the current language's translation dict.

Currently your plunker works fine. I've made a [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/3uv4P6C18G5qvJZDk2H1?p=preview), to show that it's working with links within a namespace. See where from `GREETING` takes its value.